# Spinner First Item Devider android

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am using spinner in my android application like below

```
   spino = dialog.findViewById(R.id.language_spinner);

        if (spino != null) {
            spino.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String item_position = String.valueOf(position);
                    int itemposition = Integer.parseInt(item_position);
                   String SelectedLang = String.valueOf(spino.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                    viewModel.SelectedLangPosition = itemposition;
                    switch (SelectedLang) {
                        case "English":
                            viewModel.SelectedLang = "en";
                            break;
                        case "ગુજરાતી":
                            viewModel.SelectedLang = "gu";
                            break;
                        case "हिंदी":
                            viewModel.SelectedLang = "hi";
                            break;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Its working fine as expected, but I am looking for make view divider for my first title item called choose video lanaguage, I am not getting idea how I can do it. my current look of spinner is like below

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you can do this.

The first way is to add these two lines of code to your Spinner XML:

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
android:prompt="@string/promptMsg"
```

promtMsg being "Select Language". Or you can set your title message programmatically:

Keep spinnerMode set to dialog and add this to your java code

```
spinner.setPrompt( "Select language");
```